# How to convert Matlab code to Delphi?

Tags: matlab, delphi, code-translation

How to convert this part of Matlab code to Delphi?

```
for i=1:popsize 
    fi=rand(1,dimension); % Generate a vector of uniform random numbers
    p=pbest(i,:);
    pbest(i,:)=x(i,:);
end
```

My code:

```
for i:= 1 to popsize do
begin
  fi:= // which function generates vector of uniform random numbers in Delphi?
  for k :=1 to popsize do
  begin
    p:=pbest(i,k);
    pbest(i,k):=x(i,k);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It really doesn't take much research to learn about this. Please do consider searching before asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`Random`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Random) function to generate a uniformly distributed random value. Calling [`Randomize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Randomize) once makes `Random` generate different values in each run.

```
var
  fi: array of Double;
  J: Integer;
begin
  Randomize;
  for J := 0 to dimension - 1 do
    fi[J] := Random;
end;
```

Comment: Don't call Randomize too often. Very easy to destroy randomness. Call it once at start up. Also, usually better to get a real PRNG.